# Setting graph to the secondary Y axis

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am currently working on an application on winforms in C#.
I gather data and put it into Series. I would like to draw two lines from two types of data, both of them are in the format (date,someVar) for example.
The problem that I can't seem to solve is how to match a series of points in the graph to the secondary Y axis.
For example - please see the attached graph - The first is colored purple and the second one is red.
The Y axis of the first (purple) series ranges from 0 to 400.
The Y axis of the second (red) series ranges from 0 to 1.

Since the difference between the values is very large, the second (red) series appears to be a line.
I think that the problem is that both of the series are drawn according to the primary Y axis of the first (purple) series.
I have tried setting the second (red) series to the secondary Y axis, but it didn't work.

Any advice on how to solve the issue are welcome :)

[Example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InsvM.jpg)

```
private void setupSeries()
{
arrayOfSeries[0]=new Series(varToDrawFromFirstComboBox,ViewType.Line);
arrayOfSeries[1]=new Series(varToDrawFromSecondComboBox,ViewType.Line);

chartY2.Text=varToDrawFromSecondComboBox
chatrY2.Dock=ChartTitleDockStylle.Right;
chatrY2.Font=...

chartY1.Text=varToDrawFromFirstComboBox
chatrY1.Dock=ChartTitleDockStylle.Left;
chatrY1.Font=....

chartTime.Text="Time"
chatrTime.Dock=ChartTitleDockStylle.Bottom;
chatrTime.Font=....

chart.Titles.AddRange(new ChartTitle[]{chartTime,chartY1,chartY2});
SecondaryAxisY myAxisY=new SecondaryAxisY();

((XYDiagram)chart.Diagram).SecondaryAxisY.Add(myAxisY);

xyDiagram.AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.MeasureUnit=DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeMeasureUnit.Seconds;
}
```

Comment: If that is about a DevExpress control do add this in the Tags !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete your chart layout initialization procedure, assign a newly created SecondaryAxisY element to the SeriesView.AxisY property of the second Series item.

```
    ((XYDiagram)chart.Diagram).SecondaryAxesY.Add(myAxisY);
    Series s2 = arrayOfSeries[1];
    ((LineSeriesView)s2.View).AxisY = myAxisY;
```

See also: [How to: Add Secondary Axes to a Chart](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/6245/controls-and-libraries/chart-control/examples/chart-elements/how-to-add-secondary-axes-to-a-chart)